# UIPinchGestureRecognizer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having a few issues with the Stanford 2016 CS193P course online.
I suspect the issue may be that I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 (So I cannot use identical code from the videos), but I may also have made a slip somewhere. I consulted the documentation and looked over stack overflow, but I just can't work this out.

FaceView represents a cartoon face that should scale along with a pinch (using UIPinchGestureRecognizer). To do this an outlet has been created within FaceViewController (the ViewController for FaceView):

```
@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView!{
    didSet{
    faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:faceView, action:#selector(FaceView.changeScale(recognizer:))))
    updateUI()
}
}
```

Which executes the function changeScale within the FaceView class:

```
func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .changed, .ended:
        NSLog("gesture")
        scale *= recognizer.scale
        recognizer.scale=1.0
        let resultString = "pinch - scale = \(scale))"
        NSLog(resultString)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I added an output to the console to see if the scale changes when we punch the view. Indeed it does (sample output from the console: pinch - scale = 1.10142245024732; pinch - scale = 1.11638202852033;)

But the view is not changing at all.

I'm at a complete look at this point... any help appreciated

I've confirmed that 
UserInteraction is set to True
The IBOutlet is connected (confirmed through the console output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that @Daivest was close to the answer:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:scale, y: scale)
```

I'm really unsure what changed, or why it would need this line which isn't in the tutorial - if anyone can shed some light on this it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you get the variable with scale, but you don't scale UIView.
you can do it with

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scale, scale);
```

for example.

Comment: Unfortunately CGAffineTransformIdentity is unavailable in Swift